# What will happen if mention -1 (negative) in load on startup in web.xml?

Tags: xml, servlets

While declaring load on startup, if i mention -1 in web.xml. then what will happen. is it work?

```
servlet>
<servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
<display-name>Test</display-name>
<servlet-class>com.testClass</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>-1</load-on-startup>
</servlet
```

Answer (score 0):

This setting will be ignored. Only non-negative numbers can be used here to specify loading order, lower numbers first.